# How to reset the primary key (sequence) for a PostGIS table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am uploading 64 features from 64 shapefiles into the postgis server (I use INSERT TO to append them one by one), for some reasons I made some mistakes at the first attempt so I deleted them (except where `id = 1`), then I re-upload them. However, the id (primary key generated automatically when uploading) does not start from 2 but from 65.

Why is postgis doing this? How do I change it back to start from 2? Also is there any way that I can arrange the table by the `id` in an ascending order (so that when the user drag it into QGIS and open the attribute table, they can see that the features are arranged ascendingly)?

[image: Table]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try the `ALTER SEQUENCE sequence RESTART;` command before the re-insert.

Also has the option to restart the sequence from a specified value like `ALTER SEQUENCE sequence RESTART WITH 1;`

Where `sequence` is the name of the sequence associated with that table.

As another option, if you want to empty an entire table but reset the sequence this can be done with the TRUNCATE command like `TRUNCATE table RESTART IDENTITY;` where `table` is the name of the target table being emptied and `RESTART IDENTITY` resets the sequence so that when the table is re-populated the sequence starts back at the lowest value.

For further reading have a look at [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altersequence.html) and [TRUNCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-truncate.html) docs from postgresql.